# JavaCPP with Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, javacpp

I'm trying use JavaCPP and trying to build the project in Eclipse. However, I encounter `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` when I try to make a call from my Java class to a C++ function.

I have also tried the command

> java -jar libs/javacpp.jar -classpath bin/ -classpath bin/classes/ -properties android-arm -Dplatform.root=
>   -Dcompiler.path= -d libs/armeabi/

with appropriate values filled in the blanks) that is mentioned in the README file that comes along with JavaCPP project. These things have been in vain until now. Please let me know if I'm missing something very obvious or something major. And even though `java.library.path` has been set to the appropriate value, the value is not read by the command line.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to run this in Android? Android doesn't use `java.library.path` on the command line...

Comment: @Samuel, I'm trying to write an Android NDK application. But I used `java.library.path` outside of that. Well, I did find out what I was doing wrong. It happened to be something to do with my header files. Well, I must say JavaCPP works like a charm. Thanks for giving us that.